# How can I update an existing row with new data from another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet ([example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BAWAuHgwdyiXhcQ22XRL0Ilwz4MLBlR-qwIXCmYfsi4/edit?usp=sharing)) with two sheets - Form and Data. I have the Form sheet set up so that entries can be manually input, and once the UPDATE button is clicked, the data is sent to the bottom of the Data sheet as a new row, and the Form fields are cleared, ready for the next input.

I'm trying to take this one step further - if the UPDATE button is clicked, and the Part Number field contains a value which already exists in Column A of the Data sheet (meaning it has already been entered at some point), a new row should not be added, but the existing row with the matching Part Number should be updated with the newly submitted data instead, leaving any unchanged fields at their previous values.

I've had this set up and working well years ago in Excel, but Google Sheets is a new ballgame altogether, and I have been unable to find any helpful information on how this might work with Google Sheets.

Here is the code that is working great for adding new data:

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  var values = [[formSS.getRange("B2").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B3").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B4").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B5").getValue()]];

  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(values);

  formSS.getRange("B2").clearContent(),
  formSS.getRange("B3").clearContent(),
  formSS.getRange("B4").clearContent(),
  formSS.getRange("B5").clearContent();

}
```

How can I update this code so that any already existing part numbers submitted in the Form sheet update the corresponding row on the Data sheet, instead of it being entered as a new row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works

```
function submitData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

var values = formSS.getRange("B2:B5").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
});
var partNum = values[0];
var row;
dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(function(r, i) {
    if (r[0] === partNum) {
        row = i + 1
    }
})
row = row ? row : dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var data = dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){
  return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
  })
dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 4).setValues([data]);
formSS.getRange("B2:B5").clearContent()
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that works, except it replaces all data for the row instead of just updating what changed - is there a way of leaving the Data sheet cells that did not receive any new data with their previous values and only changing the cells that received new data?

Comment: I can't see what difference that would make?

Comment: Cells that didn't need to be updated should not be cleared. For example, if I enter Part Number 123 the first time and add the Date, Material Lot, and Status, and then click Update, all that info gets added as a new line on the Data sheet. Then if I need to just change the Status next time and I enter Part Number 123 again, then the Status and submit it, it now updates on the Data sheet with the correct Part Number and Status, but the Date Received and Material Lot are empty, since I didn't add their values in again, but I still need that information.