# Google Script: How Do I match row from imported appended data using one cell and update other cells in the row with new data if changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with data imported from a Jira JQL. Twice a day I need to re-import the same JQL which currently I am doing by appending to the active sheet and then doing a data cleanup to remove duplicate rows by comparing the Issue Key column.  However this deletes the newest records and these might have an update to some of the other fields i.e. Status or Assignee.

I need a script to compare the value in the Issue Key field of the current row with all rows and if there is a match to then update the values that don't match.  (also, we don't have the Google Sheets/Jira plugin that would probably make this nice and easy).

I have 7 columns that I import, and then I have a further 5 columns that are filled in in the sheet, therefore I cannot just copy and paste the entire row.

As an test I've been using:
[test sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqtgf.png)

I've tried using [Compare data from 2 tables and overwrite the data on the first one. Apps Script Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838614/compare-data-from-2-tables-and-overwrite-the-data-on-the-first-one-apps-script) as inspiration but can't get it to work.

I've tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838614/compare-data-from-2-tables-and-overwrite-the-data-on-the-first-one-apps-script) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240292/how-can-i-update-an-existing-row-with-new-data-from-another-sheet) as inspiration but can't get it to work/don't understand what is going on enough to make it work.

I have tried in-sheet using XLOOKUP and MATCH however the issue is that the duplicate data will be deleted so this would break the formulas.

Comment: Why not have 2 sheets, one for the final results and one for the imported data?  Compare the 2 sheet, if any key matches update, if key not in results sheet append to results.  Then clear the import sheet.

Comment: That would work too. Would that be easier to write?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to merge the JQL values with the original values.  I've deliberately inserted the new values at an offset so you can see how it merged the data.  I run this from a menu option.

Here is a screen shot of my sheets.

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet1 = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
    values.shift(); // remove headers
    let sheet2 = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let jql = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
    jql.shift(); // remove headers
    let append = [];
    jql.forEach( row1 => {
        let index = values.findIndex( row2 => row2[0] === row1[0] );
        if( index < 0 ) {
          append.push(row1)
        }
        else {
          values[index] = row1;
        }
      }
    );
    values = values.concat(append);
    // to put back adjust the starting row
    sheet1.getRange(10,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

**References**

- [Google Sheets Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)
- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Array object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this.  This works if I ensure that the headers on the Import sheet (Sheet2) match Sheet1 exactly.  The only issue is on the jira import it only has 7 columns as 'ETA', 'Comment', 'Last Updated' and 'Link' aren't included.

Is there a way to do all of the above but with the import sheet just having the headings it imports?